# error MSB4067: The element <When> beneath element <Choose> is unrecognized

Tags: xml, msbuild, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
<Import Project="C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0.13.0\x64\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" />

<PropertyGroup>
    <Workspace></Workspace>
    <SolutionName></SolutionName>
    <TargetEnv></TargetEnv>
    <DeployPath></DeployPath>
    <TargetBranch></TargetBranch>
    <BuildNumber></BuildNumber>
    <Revision></Revision>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="assinfo">

<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(TargetEnv)'=='development' "> 
            <PropertyGroup>
                <Revision>1</Revision>
            </PropertyGroup>
        </When>
</Choose>
```

Msbuild shows this error:

> C:\workspace\BuildScripts\buildTEST.proj(20,3): error MSB4067: The
>   element "When" beneath element "Choose" is unrecognized.

I need to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 29):

It looks like you tried to use `<Choose>` inside a `<Target>` element. This is currently not supported by MSBuild.