# The element <When> benerath element <Choose> is unrecognized

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, msbuild

Good day I try to unload and load the project here at my work.

The error is this

> The element  beneath element  is unrecognized

I saw the same problem like mine here in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215736/error-msb4067-the-element-when-beneath-element-choose-is-unrecognized). But it doesn't have any solution .

```
<Target>

<Choose>
      <When Condition="('$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '') and '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v3.5'">
        <ItemGroup>
          <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        </ItemGroup>
      </When>
      <Otherwise>
        <ItemGroup>
          <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework">
            <Private>False</Private>
          </Reference>
        </ItemGroup>
      </Otherwise>
</Choose>
</Target>
```

I tried putting the `<Choose></Choose>` outside of the target but still no luck. Anyone knows how to fix this issue.

- Visual Studio 2017
- Windows 10
- .NET 4.5 Framework

Comment: What's the project type? C# Unit test project or what? `I tried putting the <Choose></Choose> outside of the target but still no luck.` I just tried it but it works, can you show how the script looks like after you put <choose> outside the target, so that I can reproduce it and help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215736/error-msb4067-the-element-when-beneath-element-choose-is-unrecognized/45296160 (but that one didn't mark the answer as accepted so won't mark as duplicate)

Comment: If you need using choose/when/otherweise in a target, there's https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/2056. I worked on a proof of concept for it a while ago but it wouldn't go in before a new major version of msbuild

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I resolved this issue we do have a git repository so what I did was revert the changes of my csproj from the latest build. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easily way to do it is to delete the `<Target>` and `</Target>`. See the example from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/choose-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019#example):

```
<Project  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='debug' ">
      <ItemGroup>
        ...
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='retail' ">
      <PropertyGroup>
        ...
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
        ...
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
  <Target Name="Test">
    ...
  </Target>
</Project>
```

So the correct level should be:

```
----Project
------Choose
--------When
------Target
```

The `choose` tag should be the same level like `target`. So you get the first error `The element <When> beneath element <Choose> is unrecognized`. And I assume the reason why the issue still occurs after you put the `choose` tag outside `Target` is that you didn't copy the Choose tag and its content(when...) outside together. Then you may get error like `The element <Target> beneath element <Choose> is unrecognized`.

The easy way to resolve this is to delete the `<Target> and </Target>`, then you can reload the project file. If I misunderstand anything, feel free to let me know :)